# Apache Camel Pass Parameter to multicust uri's with restlet

Tags: apache-camel, dsl, restlet

The example with GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy() worked fine with me. But now the challenge is to pass param value to the uri's. below is the code.

```java
from("restlet:http://localhost:8089/createCustomer/{foo}")      
.enrich("direct:serviceFacade")
.process(new Processor() {...})
.end();

from("direct:serviceFacade")
.multicast(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()   
    .enrich("restlet:http://localhost:8080/CamelRest/rest/restService/addressInfo/${header.foo}").enrich("restlet:http://localhost:8080/CamelRest/rest/restService/accountInfo/${header.foo}")
.end();
```

I am getting an error message:

> Header with key: header.foo not found in Exchange. Exchange[Message:
>   [Body is null]]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it Right.

```
from("direct:serviceFacade")
    .multicast(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()       
     // .bean(RecipientListBean.class, "route")       
    .enrich("restlet:http://localhost:8080/CamelRest/rest/restService/addressInfo/{foo}")
    .enrich("restlet:http://localhost:8080/CamelRest/rest/restService/accountInfo/{foo}")
      .end();
```

That would do the magic..